# Define new command that works only outside c++ comments

Tags: comments, filetype-c++

When I am coding in c++, I want vim to expand `(` into `()<++>` and place the cursor in the parenthesis. I do this by putting the following line in one of the files loaded at startup:

```
inoremap (      ()<++><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left>
```

However, I would like this binding to be disabled in comments, like

```
// Inline comment where ( shouldn't become ()<++>
```

or

```
/* Comment block where ( shouldn't become ()<++>
*/
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of expression mappings. The basic idea is to test the current syntax and only expand, if it is not a comment. That is basically what all the plugins will be hiding from you:

`:inoremap <silent><expr> ( synIDattr(synIDtrans(synID(line('.'), col('.')-1, 'name')),'name')=~?"comment"?"(":"()<++><Left><Left><Left>
<Left><Left>"`

Which means, check that the current syntax item is not of type comment and in that case replace by your ()<++> item or else replace by themselves. Note, it is probably more easier to hide that functionality behind a function that does the necessary checks.

Note: to make undo and redo work properly, instead of using "<Left>" you should use "<C-G>U<Left>", which is a relative recent addition to Vim. Read the help at `:h i_CTRL-G_U`

Comment: Great! To the point and complete. Really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

[copy paste of the answer given on SO...]

Install [lh-brackets](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-brackets/) it already detects the context to not expand anywhere. It also adds a placeholder after the closing brackets. If you directly install [lh-cpp](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-cpp), the control statements will also be context aware.

(I must admit your request is quite surprising as nobody seems to use placeholders any more. And yet lh-brackets is the plugin that (re-)introduced this concept (idea stolen from Stephen Riehm's original bracketing macros). Then [mu-template](https://github.com/LucHermitte/mu-template/) used a similar bracketing philosophy, and finally latex-suite did as well. BTW, lh-brackets should be compatible with an installed version of latex-suite)

NB: for the ones that absolutely want to define the mappings themselves, look at the [`Map*Context()` functions](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-brackets/blob/master/plugin/misc_map.vim#L200) from lh-brackets. The first version recognized comments and string contexts to not expand the *key*. The last version (`Map4TheseContext()`) permits to specify how the key should be expanded for a list of possible contexts.
The idea is to test the context with `synIDattr(synID(line('.'),col('.')-1,1),'name')`, then to interpret possible special character sequences like `<esc>`.